# Best type for JPA version field for Optimistic locking

Tags: jpa, optimistic-locking

I have doubts about which is the best type for a field annotated with @Version for optimistic locking in JPA.

The API javadoc (http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Version.html) says:

"The following types are supported for version properties: int, Integer, short, Short, long, Long, java.sql.Timestamp."

In other page (http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Locking#Optimistic_Locking) says:

"JPA supports using an optimistic locking version field that gets updated on each update. The field can either be numeric or a timestamp value. A numeric value is recommended as a numeric value is more precise, portable, performant and easier to deal with than a timestamp."

"Timestamp locking is frequently used if the table already has a last updated timestamp column, and is also a convenient way to auto update a last updated column. The timestamp version value can be more useful than a numeric version, as it includes the relevant information on when the object was last updated."

The questions I have are:

- Is better a Timestamp type if you are going to have a lastUpdated field or is better to have a numeric version field and the timestamp in other field?
- Between numeric types (int, Integer, short, Short, long, Long) which is the best to choose (considering the length of each type)? I mean, I think the best is Long but it requires a lot of space for each row.
- What happens when the version field gets to the last number of a numeric type (for example 32,767 in a Short field)? Will it start from 1 again in the next increment?

Comment: As for your last question: it does not matter how the version field is used exactly by the implementation. They could also use random values or any strategy to generate a next version in a way that avoids accidental collisions. The only important point is that the next value is different from the previous one. Also, there should be enough values to have a different value for every transaction that might be running simultaneously. Probably a byte/char could work too if they supported it. If you could guarantee that at most two transactions will ever run at the same time even a boolean would do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, know that locking is used to managed concurrent transactions.

1.Separate your concerns. If lastupdated field is business model specific, it should be separate from your versioning field - which is for - versioning.

2.Primitives and objects are usually mapped to your db as the same type. Except for the fact that Boolean by default will be nullable and boolean will be 'not nullable'. However, enforce nullability explicitly. In this case you want to use a primitive as the version field can't be nullable.

Integer or long are better than timestamp. [Hibernate recommends numeric versionig](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch05.html#d0e2251) and they don't take that much space.

3. If you use long, you might not live to find out.

Use this and you should be fine.

```
private long version;

@Version
public long getVersion() {
    return version;
}

public void setVersion(long version) {
    this.version = version;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Just go with Long or Integer.
BUT don't go with int or long. 
In opposite to other comment here, null value is expected when entity was never persisted yet.
Having int or long might make Hibernate to think that entity is already persisted and in detached state as version value will be 0 when unset.
Just finished debugging a FK violation where "int" was the cause, so save your time and just go with Long or Integer.

Comment: As stated by Piotr: "...null value is expected when entity was never persisted yet..."

Comment: Why on earth would they recommend primitive int and long if they have this problem???

Comment: @masterxilo because JPA =/= Hibernate

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a time value like Timestamp (or derivates like Instant or LocalDateTime etc...).

Especially if you have a Java < 15 application and hope to ever migrate to Java >= 15. They changed the precision of timestamps within Java to nano-seconds, but your database probably only stores up to microseconds, so it truncates the value, which will make you run into an OptimisticLockException all the time ([1](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-15166)).

Neither use a primitive value, see the answer from @Piotr: The Version field must be null for new entities.

**Just go with Long.**